# How to fix broken pipe error in python networking

Tags: networking, remote-access, python-3.5

I am creating a remote command program (like a botnet). I am using socket to do this, and when I try to send the command to the client. It throws a errno 32 broken pipe. 
Heres the code for sending

```
print("Attempting to send command "+cmd)
            verify = input("Is this the correct command y/n: ")
            if verify == "y":
                s.send(str.encode(cmd))
            if verify == 'n':
                print("Please enter your command again!")
                os.system('clear')
                remoteCommand()
            Response = conn.recv(1024)
```

And here is the receiving end code:

```
while True:
    Cmd = s.recv(1024)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation and include more code. This can happen when the receiving side closes its socket and that's likely what is happening but we can't tell that from the code you've shown.

Comment: 'Broken pipe' means you have written to a connection that had already been closed by the peer. Solution: don't. Probably you sent it some garbage it didn't understand.

Comment: I understand now, I had to decode the string on the client thank you for your help, and thanks for the explanation @EJP

Comment: Can somebody please tell me how to correctly convert the string into bytes, it's throwing the error on the send command not the recv command?